# Perl error comes in recursive function process

Tags: perl

How to solve Perl error comes up when recursive function running

```
main::getE_Path_Rec() called too early to check prototype at ./test.pl line 28
```

shown by cat -n:

```
13  our ($whole, @result);
14
15  sub getE_Path_Rec ($\@$) { my ($path, @iOffNode, $offset) = @_;
16  
17      $path=~ s#^/([^/]+)(.*)$#$2#;
18      my @OffNode;    my $eleNow=$1;
19      for (@iOffNode) {
20          $eleNow=~ m#^([^[/,]+)(?|\[(\d+|@[^]]+)\]|,(\d+))?#;
21      #
22              if($2) {
23                  getElem($1, $2-1, $_->[1], @OffNode);
24                  return undef if !@OffNode;
25                  if ($path) {
26      #
27      #
28                      getE_Path_Rec( $path, @OffNode, $offset.${$OffNode[0]}[0])
29                  }else {
30                      push( @result, [$offset, ${$OffNode[0]}[1]])
31                  }

36          }
37  
38          return
39  }
```

How do we solve such in Perl up to the recursive function seamlessly ?

Comment: (1) A suggestion: always clean up nicely what you post -- remove those line numbers (so people can copy-paste it for testing), remove comments on empty lines (?), line up braces, indent, etc.  (2)  Are you sure that those `($whole, @result)` need be `our` ?  That's a common mistake -- most of the time they should be `my`

Comment: `@iOffNode` is wrong. You want `$iOffNode`. // `our` should be `my` // And I'm failing to see the point of using prototype here. It just adds complexity for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [prototype in perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes) spell this out

> ... a recursive function with a prototype has to be predeclared for the prototype to take effect

So need

```
sub getE_Path_Rec ($\@$);          # predeclare

# later
sub getE_Path_Rec ($\@$) { ... }   # actual definition
```

Comment: Perhaps also mention that prototypes are not required, and are best left out.

Comment: @TLP I have no idea why they have a prototype there. Prototypes have a purpose and can be useful so I don't want to lecture the OP when I know nothing of their designs. (Even as a prototype in that code does appear unneeded.)

Comment: ,,, But even more, while I was going to expand the answer and clean up the question they closed this as a duplicate. (Btw, to a non-answer which doesn't "mention" anything at all but just dumps a phrase "forward declaration," what can only be mysterious to a beginner. I don't want to reopen as that technically is an answer.) So I don't see a purpose to spending time on this now.

Comment: Well, you have answered the question. Prototypes being the worst thing ever, tricking the unwary, might be a part of it. Just saying

Comment: @TLP "_you have answered the question_" -- Yeah, which was then closed for something far worse (in my opinion anyway); so I don't feel like touching it anymore, as it won't get much attention, being closed.  As for prototypes ... I've warned about them aplenty, around various comments and answers.  But it is a feature that can be used effectively and it's not my place to ban them, in particular when I have no idea what they may be intended for.  (I used them to a good effect, a few times.)

Comment: (And given that there _is_ a comment from @ikegami on that)